# Get single XML Attribute Value

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

Given the following XML -

```
<Response>
  <Item name="ItemA" />
</Response>
```

How do I get the value of the name attribute?

I have tried several ways with no luck, here was the last try-
(Note that writing the contents of 'xml' to the console displayed the above XML)

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xml)
Dim result = From x In doc.Descendants("Item") Select x.Attribute("Name").Value
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Results in output of: "System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator[Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement, String]"

Thanks,

Comment: Linq is case sensitive.  You have a capital 'N' instead of a small 'n'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that exact XML structure you can do as follows :

```
Dim result =  doc.Root.Element("Item").Attribute("name").Value
```

Notice that `Element()` returns single child element of a given name.

In case there is XML namespace involved, as you mentioned in the comment below, you need to use a combination of `XNamespace` and the element's local-name to reference `Item` element :

```
Dim path As XNamespace = "path"
Dim result = doc.Root.Element(path+"Item").Attribute("name").Value
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Dan ah the attribute is in all-lower-case *'name'*, not 'Name'

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch that. It is working. What change would need made if a namespace were added? <Response xmlns="path">

Comment: @Dan I added solution to that in the answer

Comment: Thanks for confirming that for me. All is working and your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer XElement, a lot less typing.

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    ' to load from a file
    ' Dim yourpath As String = "your path here"
    ' Dim xe As XElement = XElement.Load(yourpath)

    ' for testing
    xe = <Response>
             <Item name="ItemA"/>
         </Response>

    Dim result As String = xe.<Item>.@name '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< answer
```

Comment: @Dan - take a look at using XElement